# Bootstrap Tabs with Spaces in URL

Tags: java, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tabs

I've modified the Bootstrap Tabs slightly so that they pull the ID from a controller rather than specify them.

It is all working perfectly, however some of the ID's its pulling through have spaces between words. This is causing those Tabs not to work.

Basically, all Tabs with a Single word work fine, however those with multiple words do not work.

Here is my code:

```
<!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        @foreach (var qs in Model)
        {
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#@qs.QuestionSectionName" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">@qs.QuestionSectionName</a></li>
        }
    </ul>

    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
        @foreach (var qs in Model)
        {
           <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="@qs.QuestionSectionName">
               <table class="table">
                   <tbody>

                       @foreach (var item in qs.Questions)
                       {
                           <tr>
                               <td>
                                   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QuestionName)
                               </td>
                               <td>
                                   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QuestionSection.QuestionSectionName)
                               </td>
                           </tr>
                       }
                   </tbody>
               </table>

           </div> 
        }
    </div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When clicked, Bootstrap looks for a corresponding `.tab-pane` with a unique ID and, unfortunately, IDs **cannot** contain spaces.

You'll to hyphenate the value(s) of the `@qs.QuestionSectionName` as it steps through the loop.

Comment: Hey, Yes I am aware that this is the issue. I'm trying to find out how to replace the space with a hyphen in the string. Thanks :)

Comment: No worries! Sorry, I may have misunderstood your question a little.

Comment: Are you not able to use a PHP equivalent of [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) at all? For example: `echo str_replace(' ', '-', $qs->getQuestionSectionName);`

Comment: Sorry blue, I re-read that and it came across rude!  I've tried: `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QuestionName.Replace(' ', '-'))`           that doesn't help.

Comment: The above method I tried did work, I for some reason was using single quotes instead of double quotes. Swapping to double quotes worked.

Comment: Awesome! What language are you using (above), out of interest?

Comment: ASP.NET / MVC5 and HTML :)